# SELECT latest status grouped by user

Tags: mysql, performance, select

Im working on status table I'll show basic information per user and what filtering needs to happen having an issue getting the latest status per user and grouping by user.

So the status table information that I need to use is:

- ID
- content
- userID

and the user information I need to use is:

- ID
- locationID

So the end result of what I want to achieve is having is the latest status of each user grouped by user.

I was using:

```
SELECT ID, content
    FROM status
    WHERE content NOT RLIKE "#[0-9azA-Z]"
    AND type = "5"
    AND userID IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT ID
        FROM users
        WHERE hometownID = "'.$locationID.'"
        OR locationID = "'.$locationID.'"
    )
    GROUP BY status.userID
    ORDER BY addedDate DESC
```

And then I was grouping by user in PHP using an array of already added users and excluding them, but this is not ideal for scaling up and loading more results after, so I want a SQL only solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working for me!

```
SELECT *
FROM status
NATURAL JOIN (
    SELECT userID, MAX(addedDate) as addedDate
    FROM status
    GROUP BY userID
) AS mostRecent
WHERE userID IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT ID
    FROM users
    WHERE users.locationID = "'.$locationID.'"
    OR users.hometownID = "'.$locationID.'"
)
AND status.content NOT RLIKE "#[0-9azA-Z]"
AND type = "5"
#AND userID != "'.$userID.'"
ORDER BY status.addedDate DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Second try [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f93b0/1/0)

```
select s.userid, s.content, r.addeddate
from status s
join (select s.userid, max(s.addeddate) as addeddate
      from status s
      join users u on s.userid = u.id
      where u.hometownid = 2
            and u.locationid = 3
            and s.type = '5'
            and s.content not rlike '#[0-9a-zA-Z]'
      group by userid) r on s.userid = r.userid
                            and s.addeddate = r.addeddate;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that isn't giving one result per user.